# Multiple components in router-outlet @input decorator not working

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, components

I have a route in my router module /dashboard. In this route I have multiple components including a parent component and several child components. I pass data (tablesPanorama (Array of objects)) from the parent component called TischplanComponent (tischplan.component.ts) to a child component called DepartmentsComponent (departments.component.ts) with the @Input decorator.

**app.module.ts**

```
const appRoutes: Routes =  [
  {path: '', component: LoginComponent},
  {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
  {path: 'dashboard', component: TischplanComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
  {path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent},
  {path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]}
];
```

imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)]

**app-component-html**

This is where the router-outlet lies

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**tischplan.component.html**

```
 <app-departments [tablesPanorama]="tablesPanorama"</app-departments>
```

**departments.component.ts**

```
@Input('tablesPanorama') tablesPanorama: Table[];
```

Unfortunately the data is not passed to the child component. What causes this problem? If I console.log this.tablesPanorama in the constructor I get undefined:

```
  constructor(private tischplanService: TischplanService) {
    console.log("this.tablesPanorama:");
    console.log(this.tablesPanorama);
  }
```

**The connection between the `@Input` and the `<router-outlet>`:**

As far as I understand my code, the `@Input` is in the child component called DepartmentComponent which passes the variable tablesPanorama from the parent component TischplanComponent, which is the component of the /dashboard route in the `<router-outlet>`, which lies in the app.component.ts.

Comment: what actully you are trying to do , to pass the data to another component or you want to naviagte to another component

Comment: I only want to pass **data** to the another component

Comment: just import that component in your component then create a object of it in the constructor , then using that object pass the data to that component

Comment: Thank you. Let me try that.

Comment: `@Input()` is not supported on components added by the router. It's not clear how `@Input()` and `<router-outlet>` are related in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first: change this line -->

```
@Input() tablesPanorama: Table[];
```

you are using `@Input`, not `@Viewchild`, you don't have to specify it.

Second: wait until view initialization `ngAfterViewChecked` to read your tablesPanorama var

Comment: Or a `setTimeout(() => {}, x);` worked. Not sure if it is good practise.

Comment: not at all, `setTimeout()` is always a horrible workaround. with `ngAfterViewInit()` isn't working?

Comment: so try using `ngAfterViewChecked` instead of init.. You will see so much console log, it's not a problem, is angular that remains listening for changes of DOM. So don't worry if it happens

Comment: `ngAfterViewChecked`works. Thanks a lot for the effort!